# Change the property visible in a DropDownList through webform

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a user control inside the control have a combobox, buttons, DropDownList etc in my code add the reference:

```
   <%@ Register Src="~/UserControls/UCCom.ascx" TagName="UCCom" TagPrefix="ucc" %>

   <ucc:UCCom ID="UCCom" runat="server" MuestraFiltros="true" />
```

in the code behind i have an object, for example: this code:

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim ctrx As New UCCom
 End
```

but when i try to modify some combobox or textbox i see a message: ***Cannot access Protected field combobox here***

The code in the user control:

```
   <td style="width: 100px">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="CboUsersCom" runat="server" DataTextField="name" AutoPostBack="true"
     DataValueField="cve_user" ClientIDMode="Static" Enabled="false" Width="100px">
    </asp:DropDownList>                                   
    </td>
```

thanks for yours comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your `Page_Load` method, you can do as below:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim dropDownList As DropDownList= TryCast(UCCom.FindControl("CboUsersCom"), DropDownList)
    dropDownList.Enabled = True
End
```

Comment: thats great mean the dropdownlist its no visible when the page load, but i have doubt can i change the property visible in a <td id="colName"> similar code above ? I try but i see an exception: System.NullReferenceException, thanks again for yours comments.

Answer (score 1):

In your user control designer page i.e. usercontrol.ascx.designer change the access modifier of combobox from **'protected'** to **'public'** like below. Then you can access that control in other pages globally.

The sample code demonstrates textbox set to **'public'.**

'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' 
'     This code was generated by a tool.
'
'     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
'     the code is regenerated. 
' 
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On


Partial Public Class UserControl

'''<summary>
'''txtDateTime control.
'''</summary>
'''<remarks>
'''Auto-generated field.
'''To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
'''</remarks>
Public WithEvents txtDateTime As Global.System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox

'''<summary>
'''btnCalendar control.
'''</summary>
'''<remarks>
'''Auto-generated field.
'''To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
'''</remarks>
Protected WithEvents btnCalendar As Global.System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton

'''<summary>
'''ajaxCalendar control.
'''</summary>
'''<remarks>
'''Auto-generated field.
'''To modify move field declaration from designer file to code-behind file.
'''</remarks>
Protected WithEvents ajaxCalendar As Global.AjaxControlToolkit.CalendarExtender
End Class
```